# Python, suds, Error

Tags: python, suds

*When I'm trying get method from remote webservice it gives me error.*

**My code is:**

```
        portion=10
        start=0
        print self.stamp.datetime
        client=self.client
        while 1:
            print 'getting ids...........'
            fresh_ids=client.service.GetTopicsIDsUpdatedAfterDateTime(self.stamp.datetime,start,portion) #this line makes exception
            if len(fresh_ids) is not 0:
                for id in fresh_ids:
                    yield id
                start=+portion
            else:
                print 'No updated topics anymore'
                sys.exit()
```

**There is trace-back:**

```
 /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/suds-0.3.5-py2.5.egg/suds/client.py
in invoke(self, args, kwargs)
    469         binding = self.method.binding.input
    470         binding.options = self.options
--> 471         msg = binding.get_message(self.method, args, kwargs)
    472         timer.stop()
    473         metrics.log.debug(

/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/suds-0.3.5-py2.5.egg/suds/bindings/binding.py
in get_message(self, method, args, kwargs)
     96         content = self.headercontent(method)
     97         header = self.header(content)
---> 98         content = self.bodycontent(method, args, kwargs)
     99         body = self.body(content)
    100         env = self.envelope(header, body)

/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/suds-0.3.5-py2.5.egg/suds/bindings/rpc.py
in bodycontent(self, method, args, kwargs)
     61             p = self.mkparam(method, pd, value)
     62             if p is not None:
---> 63                 root.append(p)
     64             n += 1
     65         return root

/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/suds-0.3.5-py2.5.egg/suds/sax/element.py
in append(self, objects)
    329                 child.parent = self
    330                 continue
--> 331             raise Exception('append %s not-valid' %
child.__class__.__name__)
    332         return self
    333

<type 'exceptions.Exception'>: append list not-valid
```

**There is the method in `suds` module which raises an Exception:**

```
def insert(self, objects, index=0):
        """
        Insert an L{Element} content at the specified index.
        @param objects: A (single|collection) of attribute(s) or element(s)
            to be added as children.
        @type objects: (L{Element}|L{Attribute})
        @param index: The position in the list of children to insert.
        @type index: int
        @return: self
        @rtype: L{Element}
        """
        objects = (objects,)
        for child in objects:
            if isinstance(child, Element):
                self.children.insert(index, child)
                child.parent = self
            else:
                raise Exception('append %s not-valid' % child.__class__.__name__)
        return self
```

In the console everything is going well.
I'm stuck.

**Ok, I tried to make an experiment:**

```
def YieldID(self):
        portion=10
        start=0
        print self.stamp.datetime
        fresh_ids=self.client.service.GetTopicsIDsUpdatedAfterDateTime(self.stamp.datetime,start,portion) #This work
        while 1:
            print 'getting ids...........'
            fresh_ids=self.client.service.GetTopicsIDsUpdatedAfterDateTime(self.stamp.datetime,start,portion) # This raise exception
            if len(fresh_ids)!=0:
                for id in fresh_ids:
                    yield id
                start=+portion
            else:
                print 'No updated topics anymore'
                sys.exit()
```

I add calling of the same method before WHILE end it work. But when it go inside while gives me exception.

**How it can work before loop, and don't work inside loop?** That is the main question. What changed?

I even tried changing `while` to `for`.

Comment: Not related to your problem but `if len(fresh_ids) is not 0:` is not a good idea. At least use `if len(fresh_ids) != 0:`, or simply `if len(fresh_ids):`

Comment: Yes but exception begins before that part of code. But anyway i changed it. Thanks.

Comment: Which line in _your_ code causes the exception?

Comment: fresh_ids=client.service.GetTopicsIDsUpdatedAfterDateTime(self.stamp.datetime,start,portion)

Comment: It using suds module to connect to remote Web-Service+

Comment: What does the XML look like that the service returns?

Comment: I dont know. But suds gives me JSON.

Comment: How it can work before loop, and don't work inside loop. That is the main question. What changed?

Comment: Your line `start=+portion` needs to be changed to `start += portion` (adding whitespace helps to make the problem more visible.) Please also see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** On another look at the code, I noticed that this line:

```
            start=+portion
```

needs to be changed to

```
            start += portion
```

That might make the following analysis unnecessary... but I think there *might* still be an issue in your suds source, as explained below.

---

The first question I'd ask is: Are you sure that nothing is changing inside your `self.client` object between calls to `YieldID`?

The other concern I have -- which may well be indicative of nothing at all -- is that you may have posted the wrong source for the function where the Exception is raised. The traceback shows that the Exception is raised during a call to `append`, but the code you included is for `insert`. It looks as if `insert`'s Exception message identifies it as "append" due to a copy and paste error.

And there's more. Assuming that I've identified the [right source location](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/browser/trunk/suds/sax/element.py?rev=462), here's the full source for `append`, which starts with line number 313:

```
def append(self, objects):
    """
    Append the specified child based on whether it is an
    element or an attrbuite.
    @param objects: A (single|collection) of attribute(s) or element(s)
        to be added as children.
    @type objects: (L{Element}|L{Attribute})
    @return: self
    @rtype: L{Element}
    """
    if not isinstance(objects, (list, tuple)):
        objects = (objects,)
    for child in objects:
        if isinstance(child, Element):
            self.children.append(child)
            child.parent = self
            continue
        if isinstance(child, Attribute):
            self.attributes.append(child)
            child.parent = self
            continue
        raise Exception('append %s not-valid' % child.__class__.__name__)
    return self
```

Here, the Exception is raised on line **334**, not **331** as your traceback shows.

**Are you sure that you're using the original version of suds 0.3.5, and not a modified version?** Because the original version of `append` has an interesting difference with `insert`: `insert` **always** creates a tuple out of its input argument, which seems redundant at best:

```
def insert(self, objects, index=0): // line 337
    # ... snip to line 348
    objects = (objects,)
```

whereas the original `append` does this conditionally (see above):

```
    if not isinstance(objects, (list, tuple)):
        objects = (objects,)
```

Now look at the message in the exception:

> : append
>   list not-valid

This means that the child that it tried to append was itself a list. But how could this be? If a list had been passed in as input, then we should be iterating through the children of that list... which should not themselves be lists.

Hmm. Perhaps a doubly-nested list had been passed into `append` as the object parameter, which would seem to indicate some pretty bad corruption of data structures. (See my first question.)

Or...

**What follows is sheer speculation, and can't possibly be right** ... unless it is...

Or, maybe, you're using a modified version of Suds in which that conditional conversion to a list has been removed, along with the iteration through the list? That would explain the 3-line difference (331 vs. 334) between the code you posted and the source that I found online. Could you double-check the source file that you're using, and let us know for sure?

Comment: You right. It not my trace-back, i was thincking that it is the smae like my. I just cant copy fron my console and find similar traceback in some forum. Sorry. I was thinking that it is tha smae.

Comment: Thanks. In the library that you're using, does the definition of `append` match the original version, or has it been modified?

Comment: Thanks. That still leaves me puzzled about the difference in line numbers. But please fix the '=+' and see if it works now.